# Discord.py warning

Tags: discord, discord.py, warnings

I've been working on a moderator discord bot. Made all the command except the warn command. Can anyone help me to make a warn command.

If the member (with manage member permission) types `?warn @user` reason the bot will save the warning in a file

And if the user says `?warnings @user` the bot will show the warnings of the user also an unwarn command like when the user says `?unwarn @user` bot should be able to unwarn the specified user.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please include your code, approaches and errors you face. You may also take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as nobody will code all of this for you. StackOverflow is **not** a "code this for me"-platform.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean this?

```py
def save_warn(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    with open('warns.json', 'r') as f:
         warns = json.load(f)

         warns[str(member.id)] += 1

    with open('warns.json', 'w') as f:
         json.dump(warns, f)

def remove_warn(ctx, member: discord.Member, amount: int):
    with open('warns.json', 'r') as f:
         warns = json.load(f)

         warns[str(member.id)] -= amount

    with open('warns.json', 'w') as f:
         json.dump(warns, f)
    
def warns_check(member: discord.Member):
    with open('warns.json', 'r') as f:
         warns = json.load(f)

         warns[str(member.id)]
    return warns

@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def warn(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason):
      save_warn(ctx, member)
      dm = await bot.fetch_user(member.id)
      em=discord.Embed(title="Warning", description=f"Server: {ctx.guild.id}\nReason: {reason}"
      await dm.send(embed=em)

@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def warnings(ctx, member: discord.Member):
      warns = warns_check(member)
      await ctx.send(f"{member.name} has {warns} warnings.")

@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def rmwarn(ctx, member: discord.Member, amount: int):
      remove_warn(ctx, member, amount)
      await ctx.send(f"Removed {amount} warnings from {member.name}!")
```